# Python3, Tkinter GUI crashes and button remain clicked

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I made a code that includes an infinite loop and made a Tkinter interface that has a start button.

When I click the button windows thinks the GUI has crashed -even tho it's working in the background-, and the button remain clicked.

-How do I unclick the button ?

-and how do I make the same Tkinter window start a new loop when clicked again ? making the window stay responsive.

sample code:

```
import time
from tkinter import *

def do():
    while x > 0:
        try:
            x = 1
            x += 1
            return x
        except:
            time.sleep(x)
            x = 0

window = Tk()

Button(text='Start',width=30, command=do).grid(row=0, column=0)

mainloop()
```

Where `except` has an exception error that is deemed to happen,

To add some context I'm using this along with selenium library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple of problems here:

1.) `do()` is not preceded by `def`.

2.) `expect` should be `except`

3.) Your `while` loop is blocking the flow of your program. Instead you should use `Tk().after(wait_time, method)`

With that being said, I'm assuming that you want to count up after the button is pressed.

This starts counting from 0 after the button is clicked.
When the button is clicked again, it stops printing `count` and resets it:

```
from tkinter import *

class App:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()

        self.count = 0
        self.do_count = False

        self.button = Button(self.root, text="Click me.", command=self.do)
        self.button.pack()

        self.root.mainloop()

    def do(self):
        self.do_count = not self.do_count
        if not self.do_count:
            self.count = 0
        self.update()

    def update(self):
        if self.do_count:
            print(self.count)
            self.count += 1
            self.root.after(1000, self.update)


app = App()
```

Comment: Thank you, I corrected the first couple mistakes,

but I'm still trying to grasp my third one, I'm new so it'll take a while, I will look up pack() and after() and get back to you once I've implemented them into my code with the result if your interest in this question survived until then.

Comment: `pack()` just places the widget in the next default position that tkinter specifies. In my example `after()` waits 1000 milliseconds (1 second) and then calls the `update()` method (itself) again.

Comment: `after()` just ensures that the method is called every so often. A while loop makes the program hang because it can never exit that loop, so the program cannot continue execution.

Comment: Tried it, it worked to some degree
I made the button command call another function that calls the one I want done. The one with the while loop, it then crashed again, I suppose an infinite for or if loop will cause the same issue, won't it ?

Comment: @T.Galisnky Yes. Anything that is an "infinite" loop is blocking. (Unless it is in it's own seperate thread, but thats another story.) Therefore, it won't continue to the rest of the program. Tkinter handles things in it's main loop in the background. If you call a function that blocks the program from returning to it's main loop (like a while loop), then the program will crash because it cannot continue execution.

Comment: reading an article on threading at the moment, thanks for showing me the thread to follow, marked as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
import threading
import time
from tkinter import *

def clicked():
    threading.Thread(target=do).start()

def do():
    while x > 0:
        try:
            x = 1
            x += 1
            return x
        except:
            time.sleep(x)
            x = 0

window = Tk()

Button(text='Start',width=30, command=clicked).grid(row=0, column=0)

mainloop()
```

Use at your own risk as this by it self won't enable you to break the loop, will update if I found a way

Edit:

Simplest solution is to make daemon thread, this helps close your code if you closed the GUI, you can do this by editing a line from the code above like this:

```
threading.Thread(target=do, daemon=True).start()
```